# keybinding: move cursor to specific column (for comments)

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, key-bindings, cursor-position

I am rather new to sublime text but wanted to make a key binding to move the cursor to a specific/constant column, regardless of any previous text entered. This would be used to add comments to code on the far right, or just improving uniformity in coding verilog (or other language).

Basically after any entered text, hit ctrl+1 (or any other key binding) and cursor goes to a specified column adding spaces as filler.

Here is what I have so far.

```
  [{ "keys": ["ctrl+1"],
    "command": "run_multiple_commands",
    "args": {
      "commands": [
        { "command": "move_to", "args": {"to": "eol", "extend": false} },
        { "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": " "} },
        { "command": "insert_snippet", "args": {"contents": "$TM_LINE_INDEX"} },
        { "command": "move", "args": {"by": "words", "forward": false} },

        { "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t\t\t\t"},"context":
        [
          { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "40", "match_all": true }
        ]
         },

        { "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t\t\t"},"context":
        [
          { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "41", "match_all": true }
        ]
         },

        { "command": "delete_word", "args": { "forward": true } }

      ]
    }
  }]
```

The way I have the code setup is (STEP 3 IS NOT WORKING):

1. I have a .py script to run multiple commands for a single key binding. [Link](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=8677)
2. Get current column number through a snippet command($TM_LINE_INDEX) and move cursor left of number.
3. ATTEMPT to use regex to add according number of tabs/spaces. I've only added two cases, but this would be repeated for various cursor column_#'s(locations), not just cursor column locations 40 and 41. Below is the non-working block of code.

   ```
       { "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t\t\t\t"},"context":
       [
         { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "40", "match_all": true }
       ]
        },

       { "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "\t\t\t"},"context":
       [
         { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "41", "match_all": true }
       ]
        },
   ```
4. Delete the trailing column number snippet (from step 2).

Thanks in advance for any help or comments.

Comment: Does your code/command work? If so, what part are you stuck on?

Comment: Everything works except the regex_match to determine if the insert command should be used. All commands before it work ok, and the last "delete_word" command works but is being blocked by the regex (will work too if moved above the two regex's).

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help - it's been too long! Try "40$" or perhaps "regex_contains". Maybe someone else will assist. Good luck.

Comment: I gave it a go, but no luck. Thanks for the suggestions though! I'll keep trying other things. The regex still seems to be the hold up.